# <img> fixed at point, until next point

Tags: javascript, html, position, fixed

I don't know Javascript very well. A div tag that has the id "theFixed" works with only one javascript line at a time (max vs min, but I need both to work at the same time. Here is my code right now. How would I put the "max" and "min" lines into one.

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
$("#theFixed").css("top",Math.max(0,1500-$(this).scrollTop()));
$("#theFixed").css("top",Math.min(0,3000-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
</script>

<div id="theFixed" style="position:fixed;top:2px;bottom:2px;">
<img src="../images/90s/rooms/90s%20room_full_color.png">
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Move both into one assignment:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){  
  $("#theFixed").css(
    "top",
    Math.min(
     Math.max(0, 1500 - $(this).scrollTop()),
     3000 - $(this).scrollTop()
    )
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonaswilms you're legendary! ily